# Problem upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

In attempting to upgrade 21.10 with the following I'm told to "install all available updates".

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-proposed InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnetsnmptrapd40 libsnmp-dev libsnmp40
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

It would seem that the three packages libnetsnmptrapd40, libsnmp-dev and libsnmp40 are preventing the upgrade. What more do I need to do?

How do I overcome this?

Comment: have you run `apt full-upgrade` on your system to upgrade packages, and checked for *holds* you may have run (`apt-mark showhold`) ?    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades

Comment: Yes I've done that with no change

Comment: Try deleting the packages and reinstalling them after you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

HPLIP was causing the problem. Removed that and all worked well.